# How to get batch/bulk messages from azure queue without using azure sdk?

Tags: java, azure, jms, jms-topic, azure-queues

i am using createQueueBrowser() of JMS but it is not giving any response, i mean enumerator is null. is there any alternatives for getting bulk message from the azure queue and also are there any ways to traverse the queue without using azure java sdk..

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is just a wrapper around the REST API. You can use that to manage your queue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/queue-service-rest-api

But I would check if the queue really is empty, before changing over to the REST API from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept `azure queue` in your description which is not clear for me. I don't know what you said is either Azure Queue Storage or Azure ServiceBus Queue. Based on my understanding, I think azure queue as you said is Azure ServiceBus Queue, not Queue Storage, because only ServiceBus Queue support AMQP via JMS in Java.

For using Service Bus Queue, there are there ways in Java for you.

1. Using Azure SDK for Java like offical tutorial [`How to use Service Bus queues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues) said.
2. Using JMS with AMQP protocol like another offical tutorial [`How to use the Java Message Service (JMS) API with Service Bus and AMQP 1.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp) said.
3. The last way is using [Service Bus Runtime REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest) based on HTTP protocol if the above two ways are not you want.